# Wifi keep on disconnecting on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi

I am using ubuntu. wifi works great on my laptop. I am facing problem with one particular wifi router (I think Airtel Binatone) installed in my company premises,

Here are some logs

1) sudo iwlist scan

```
Cell 01 - Address: 00:18:0A:21:9E:EE
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"314eMeraki1"
                    Bit Rates:11 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000004572cfe90
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000B333134654D6572616B6931
                    IE: Unknown: 010896960C1218243048
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1E
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0103
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 3202606C
                    IE: Unknown: 460573C0010000
                    IE: Unknown: 33020C01
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A8C011BFFFF000000000000000000008000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101040003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD0D00180A07240000000100EC3E78
          Cell 02 - Address: 00:18:0A:21:29:FC
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"314eMeraki1"
                    Bit Rates:11 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000003f1d88965
                    Extra: Last beacon: 8ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000B333134654D6572616B6931
                    IE: Unknown: 010896960C1218243048
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B1E
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0103
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 3202606C
                    IE: Unknown: 460573C0010000
                    IE: Unknown: 33020C01
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A8C011BFFFF000000000000000000008000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101080003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DD0D00180A07160000000100EC3E78
```

2) dmesg

```
[ 1768.252817] wlan0: authenticate with 00:18:0a:21:29:fc
[ 1768.272963] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:0a:21:29:fc (try 1/3)
[ 1768.276056] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1768.280370] wlan0: associate with 00:18:0a:21:29:fc (try 1/3)
[ 1768.283766] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:18:0a:21:29:fc (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=5)
[ 1768.284015] wlan0: associated
[ 1768.284081] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 1768.286074] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 1768.286078] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: FCC
[ 1768.286079] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 1768.286082] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1768.286083] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1768.286085] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1768.286086] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1768.286087] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 1768.286089] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1768.286090] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1771.795816] wlan0: disassociated from 00:18:0a:21:29:fc (Reason: 2)
[ 1771.811893] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1771.817867] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1771.817876] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 1771.817879] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 1771.817885] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1771.817890] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1771.817894] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1771.817898] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 1771.817901] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
```

==========

```
authenticate with 00:18:0a:21:9e:ee
[ 2435.747062] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:0a:21:9e:ee (try 1/3)
[ 2435.748843] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2435.750491] wlan0: associate with 00:18:0a:21:9e:ee (try 1/3)
[ 2435.753988] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:18:0a:21:9e:ee (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=13)
[ 2435.754237] wlan0: associated
[ 2435.754768] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 2435.756678] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 2435.756681] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: FCC
[ 2435.756682] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 2435.756684] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm), (N/A)
[ 2435.756686] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm), (N/A)
[ 2435.756687] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 2435.756688] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 2435.756689] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[ 2435.756690] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 2435.756692] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 2436.565119] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:18:0a:21:9e:ee by local choice (Reason: 14=MIC_FAILURE)
[ 2436.576178] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 2436.578321] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 2436.578325] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[ 2436.578326] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[ 2436.578329] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 2436.578331] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 2436.578333] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 2436.578335] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[ 2436.578336] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)


on one cell, i am getting 
Reason: 14=MIC_FAILURE
on second cell,
Reason: 2
```